# Переделать preg_replace в preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, php7

Подскажите, как переделать функцию `preg_replace` в `preg_replace_callback`, вот строка:

```
$error = preg_replace('#^([A-Z_]+)$#e', "(!empty(\$user->lang['\\1'])) ? \$user->lang['\\1'] : '\\1'", $error);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то так:

```
$error = preg_replace_callback('#^([A-Z_]+)$#', function ($m) use ($user) {
    return (!empty($user->lang[$m[1]])) ? $user->lang[$m[1]] : $m[1];
}, $error);
```